# Piking servomotor from datasheet

Tags: servo

Hi I saw several datasheets from servo that use kg-cm units and other that use kg/cm I think that is a misspelling error, this is not my problem I assume that the unit most be kg-cm in units of torque force times distance. 
Ok, so when the units are in N-m there not problem by when they use kg I'm not sure if they are talking about kg in terms of mass or kg in terms of force, because one is about ten time bigger than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kg, when used as part of the units for servo torque, always means 9.81N.

kg is an incorrect but customary substitute for kgf, which is the force required to support 1kg in earth's nominal surface gravity. Even if the manufacturer did mean kg to represent mass, he actually means the force required to support that mass, that is kgf. It's the tension on a string that supports that mass.

When measuring torque, the units are always force × distance. It's customary for servo manufacturers to write that incorrectly as well. In context therefore, kg-cm does not mean mass minus cm, but means kgf × cm. Similarly kg/cm does not mean kg mass per cm, but kgf × cm. The correct way to write that unit would be kgf×cm.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not matter as long as you are on earth.

1 kgf is the force applied by 1kg mass on planet earth.

But of course, they would not be the first manufacturer to use the wrong units either.

You can always test it by taping and wrapping a bit of string around the shaft, or a pulley, and hanging a mass on the end and see what it will pull up at the rated terminal voltage.

Comment: are you sure 1kg exerts a force of 9.81kgf????? Look up kgf on wikipedia. I'm not sure I understand what your second paragraph means.

Comment: @Neil_UK ak I was thinking newtons DUH.. early here